# Insert keys in a new array provided by another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following loop:

```
for($column = 'A'; $column != $lastColumn; $column++) {
          for ($row = 2; $row <= 6; $row++) {
              $cell[] = $objWorksheet->getCell($column.$row)->getFormattedValue();
              if($column == 'A') {
                $arrayTeste = array('A' => $cell);
              } else {
                $arrayTeste = array('B' => $cell);
              }
          }
      }
```

What I want is: I want to make a new array with key 'A' using the values in 'cell' array. Because in another part of my code I need to echo just the values inside 'A' key. Like when you echo from a DB index. Example: echo $array['A']. Also in this second part, I'll need a foreach to print all the array, right?

Comment: that's not going to work. you keep overwriting `arrayTeste` on every loop iteration, and will end up with only the LAST value when both loops exit.

Comment: please, show an example and I'll help you

Comment: Why don't you just use the `rangeToArray()` method that's already buit into PHPExcel?

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. With the reply of Felippe I was able to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your data inside an array, indexed by your column:

```
$cell = [];
for($column = 'A'; $column != $lastColumn; $column++) {
    for ($row = 2; $row <= 6; $row++) {
        $cell[$column][] = $objWorksheet->getCell($column.$row)->getFormattedValue();
    }
}
```

Output will be something like:

```
['A'] =>
   [0] => 'cella1',
   [1] => 'cella2',
['B'] =>
   [0] => 'cellb1',
   [1] => 'cellb2',
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current code is that you are going to be overwriting `$arrayTeste` each time you go through the loop. This can be solved with a multidimensional array as follows:

```
if($column == 'A') {
    $arrayTeste[$column][$row] = array('A' => $cell);
} else {
    $arrayTeste[$column][$row] = array('B' => $cell);
}
```